# why does python obj.atribute return adress location and obj.atribute.atribute return the value?

Tags: python, list, callable-object

To get the value of an attribute I need to call method.attribute.attribute instead of method.attribute, why is this? Calling method.attribute results in a memory address. How should/can I change my code to make method.attribute work?

Most issues regarding this center around calling print(f) instead of print(f())

```
class MyList:
    """stores a list and does other stuff eventualy"""
    this_list = []

    def __init__(self, *args):
        for arg in args:
            self.this_list.append(arg)

    def print_list(self):
        """prints the atribute:"description" from the stored objects in the list"""
        for x in range(len(self.this_list)):
            print(MyClassObj(self.this_list[x]).description, sep="\n")
```

This is the code that is supposed to print the value of the attribute *description*

```
class MyClassObj:
    """test object to be stores in the "MyList" object."""

    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description
```

This is the object that contains the attribute I want to get.

```
class CallList:
    """creates the objects, lists and calls the print method"""
    @staticmethod
    def main():
        test1, test2 = MyClassObj("Test1"), MyClassObj("Test2")
        list1 = MyList(test1, test2)
        list1.print_list()
```

Main() is called outside the above classes.

The output I get is

```
<__main__.MyClassObj object at 0x007908F0>
<__main__.MyClassObj object at 0x00790910>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

If i change line:

```
print(MyClassObj(self.this_list[x]).description.description, sep="\n")
```

I get the expected result:

```
Test1
Test2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So the question is why and how should I alter my code?

Comment: Unrelated, but `this_list` is *shared* by every instance of `MyList`.

Comment: That was my intention thanks! I just read about class variables and instance variables.

Comment: It's hard to tell from this example, but it looks like you are using classes where none are really needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `print_list` `self.this_list[x]` is already a `MyClassObj` so `MyClassObj(self.this_list[x])` creates a new `MyClassObj` having a `MyClassObj` as its `description`.

Because there is no way defined to convert a `MyClassObj` to a string for `print` Python uses a default conversion showing the memory address.

Comment: Thank you that fixed it! The reason I added MyClassObj(..) to the print function was to show the attributes of the object when calling it. Without it I don't get a list of available attributes even though it does work. How can I get the hints to show up in this case? EDIT: I got it to work.    for x in range(len(self.this_list)):
            obj: MyClassObj = self.this_list[x]
            print(obj.description, sep="\n")